# az devops powershell passing space delimited values

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli2

The AZ devops command
`az pipelines variable-group create` takes --variables defined as "Variables in format key=value space separated pairs"

I need to create a variable group with 20+ key=value pairs.  I'm finding it hard to do so as a variable.

This command line works

```
 az pipelines variable-group create --name myname --variables “owner=Firstname Lastname” “application=cool-name”
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$tags ={owner='Firstname Lastname' application='cool-name'} 
az pipelines variable-group create --name owgroup --variables $tags
```

I looked at this article that showed promise but the recommended answer(s) doesn't work
[Space separated values; how to provide a value containing a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349758/space-separated-values-how-to-provide-a-value-containing-a-space)

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
$tags=(“owner=Firstname Lastname”, “application=cool-name”)
az pipelines variable-group create --name owgroup --variables $tags
```

I have not AZ DevOps but validate a similar scenario with Azure CLI on PowerShell ISE. If you are running Az CLI on Bash, you could follow your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350520/9833314).

[image]

Comment: who knew an array would work when defined as "Variables in format key=value space separated pairs", but it did, thanks for that help!