# psql: warning: extra command-line argument "from" ignored

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I am trying to execute a non-interactive postgres command.

```
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgresql -d $PGDB --command "select count(*) from services"
```

Which has been giving me this response.

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "from" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "services;" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "mydbname" ignored
>
> psql: FATAL:  database "count(*)" does not exist

I've read that this could be because the terminal / bash is trying to break up each argument to `--command` / `-c` as it's own argument.

I've also tried this:

```
PSQLARGS=(-h 127.0.0.1 -U postgresql -c )
PSQLARGS+=("select count(*) from services;")
PSQLARGS+=(${PGDB})
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql "${PSQLARGS[@]}"
```

Some way of forcing the terminal to know it's one argument, this also didn't work.

Comment: Writing `$PGDB` or `$PGPASS` is unsafe because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819423/bash-variables-with-spaces but aside from that, this command line looks like it can't produce these error messages. Can you provide a reproducible test case?

Comment: @ThomasReggi I'm having the same exact problem.  Ever get any solution to this?

Comment: @MikeyE Check out my solution below and let me know if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60263058/178728

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty cheap and common error.
Putting everything in quotes should do the trick.

Try this:

```
PGPASSWORD="$PGPASS" psql -h '127.0.0.1' -U 'postgresql' -d "$PGDB" --command "select count(*) from services"
```

Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Yep PGDB probably had spaces in it...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like $PGDB is empty, so psql thinks --command is the name of the database.

Comment: This is not the case. I've logged out `$PGDB` and placed `-d $PGDB` at different parts of the command, as well as just having `$PGDB` at the end. Nothing is working.

Comment: Interesting.  What shell are you using?  bash?